# Is there a way to display a thumbnail image of a contact list contact, using the highlighted content web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, thumbnail, highlighted-content-web-part

I'm using Sharepoint on Office 365. When I'm using the highlighted content web part for PDFs and DOCs, I can see a preview of the document in the thumbnail view. When I'm using the highlighted content to display people from my contact list, I don't get any preview in the thumbnail, it's just a white box.

When I'm viewing my contacts as a List, I can see their image in the "photo" column (because I've uploaded their photos as attachments".

Is there any way to have this photo shown in the thumbnail view when I'm viewing contacts as highlighted content?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to display thumbnail images of a contact list when using highlighted content web part.